# local flutter asset image not showing in html widget

Tags: html, image, flutter, dart, assets

I am using flutter_html to render html code and it is working well but I am having a problem with img tag

The img tag work well when the image is from the web like this:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
```

but it doesn't work when it's a local asset image file
Note: I can use the same image in an Image widget like this:

```
Image.asset('assets/images/logo_tst.png'),
```

but it wont show in html code and I tried all these:

```
String htmlUrl = '''  
<img src="file:///storage/assets/images/logo_tst.png" alt="web-img1" >
<img src="file:///assets/images/logo_tst.png" alt="web-img2">
<img src="file:///images/logo_tst.png" alt="web-img3">
''';
```

then I call it:

```
Html( data:htmlUrl),
```

And it only shows the alt:

```
web-img1
web-img2
web-img3
```

I am testing on an Android emulator and a device

what Am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it! I have found a solution and it wasn't obvious and not documented anywhere!

after searching for days the right way to use assets with the img tag I have decided to take a look at the source code of flutter_html in github and I have found these two lines:

```
else if (node.attributes['src'].startsWith('asset:')) {
                  final assetPath = node.attributes['src'].replaceFirst('asset:', '');
```

so I tried the img tag like this:

```
<img src="asset:assets/images/logo_tst.png" alt="web-img2">
```

By the way my image file is declared in `pubspec.yaml` as

```
assets/images/logo_tst.png
```

And It worked !!!

As I said there is no documentation about this and I hope that someone will add it

Comment: I tried this, something has been happened, before used this I am able to see only the empty rectangle but now I can see the question mark.
could you share some information about this type of issue.
Because image  is place at the same path assets/images/<image1>

Comment: @SumeetMourya did u find any solution?

Comment: @MonikaPatel not yet, for now I used the base64 data for the image, as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/" + url
```

in other words:

```
"file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/images/logo_tst.png"
```

Comment: I have tried it and it didn't work and assets/images/logo_tst.png is the url as declared in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the webview_flutter cannot read local CSS or local images(jpg/png file) by now.  I have to change it to inline CSS and based64 images and it works perfectly.

Inline CSS:

```
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: linen;
}

h1 {
  color: maroon;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Inline base64 images:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RiDRXhpZgAATU0AKgA...">
```

To convert an image to base64 image in Mac, you can run the following command in Terminal.

```
openssl enc -base64 -in image.png -out image.b64
```